# Can I turn off calls in Viber Desktop?

Tags: viber

can I turn off calls in Viber Desktop? So I won't receive it in the desktop app, I only want to receive calls in mobile app.

Comment: Change `Settings - Calls and Message` and enable "Viber-In calls" on your mobile  - this will **enable your phone to receive incoming calls with Viber whenever possible.**

Answer (score 0):

If its macOS then following worked for me. This is about updating the sound file for ring tone. But if you update the app you will have to do this again.

```
mv /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Ringtone/ringtone.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Ringtone/ringtone.wav_bak
cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/silence.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Ringtone/ringtone.wav


cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/Sticker1.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/Sticker1.wav_bak
cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/silence.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/Sticker1.wav
cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/incoming_fg.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/incoming_fg.wav_bak
cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/silence.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/incoming_fg.wav
cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/outgoing_fg.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/outgoing_fg.wav_bak
cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/silence.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/outgoing_fg.wav
cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/incoming_bg.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/incoming_bg.wav_bak
cp /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/silence.wav /Applications/Viber.app/Contents/Resources/Sound/Messages/incoming_bg.wav
```